# PHP Get dynamic value from string

Tags: php, string, dynamic

I'm trying to get a dynamic value from a string. But nothing shows up.

```
ob_start();
var_dump($torrent->result['info']['pieces']);
$pieces = ob_get_clean();
$piecescorrected = explode($pieces, 'string(*)');
echo $piecescorrected;`
```

Whats up with this?

Edit:
Some clarification.
$pieces needs to be filter from all the other random characters after it.
Output of $pieces:

```
string(12620) "< ÏÚÿÊÜµä¬§âW—µ-‘CÄÞ½§§¼ø0LØëÍI­×L —@c õL2“iÓ¹ý¼Bl'-“’4žþÊYï‡
```

Now $pieces needs to be corrected by filtering out `string(12620)`
But the value is dynamic so therefore I used `$piecescorrected = explode($pieces, 'string(*)');`
Mind the * in **string(*)**

Comment: This may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting (For your asking)

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($pieces);` ?

Comment: string(12620) with random stuff after it.

Comment: Okay if it is so long, just post a pastbin link in the comments that we can actually look at the output

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RqG3wi98

Comment: Why don't you just do: `echo $piecescorrected= $torrent->result['info']['pieces'];` ?!?

Comment: Because I still get all the random characters after that.

Comment: I though you only want to get rid of `string(12620)` and keep the rest?!

Comment: Nope I want to keep string(12620) and get rid of the rest.

Comment: ^ Ah now I get it! Why don't just use: `echo strlen($torrent->result['info']['pieces']);` ?!

Comment: Should I convert it into an answer?

Comment: Sure why not? Extra text dont mind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521876/php-get-dynamic-value-from-string?noredirect=1#comment47199357_29521876) you actually wanted just the string length.

So you don't need any output buffering or explode() calls. Just use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) like this:

```
echo strlen($torrent->result['info']['pieces']);
```

output:

```
12620
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's up with it:  `explode()` is looking for a literal string. It doesn't take wildcards.

If you had a string like `1,2,3,4` you could use `explode(',', '1,2,3,4')` to get an array of those values by splitting on comma.  Here, you could split on the literal `'string'` but not `'string(*)'`.